# Facebook Like Box faces not appearing when logged into Facebook

Tags: plugins, facebook-likebox

When logged out of Facebook, I see all the faces in the Like Box as shown here:
http://allben.net/misc/facebook_logged_out.png

When logged into Facebook, none of the faces are showing as shown here:
http://allben.net/misc/facebook_logged_in.png

My Facebook account is also an admin for the Facebook Pages, which may or may not be related.

This is happening on several sites I have, one example:
http://www.azom.com/

The problem started probably about 2 or 3 weeks ago.  The same behavior in both Firefox and Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: The same issue is showing up in Mobile Safari too when logged into Facebook, so definitely not a browser issue (as stated in the question, this is happening in Chrome and Firefox too).

Comment: About 3 days ago, the faces started appearing again on all my devices.  I didn't make any changes and suspect it may have been a problem on Facebook's end they fixed.